# Map composer issue

Tags: qgis, cartography, print-composer

I am using QGis (latest version, OS X) and whan I create a map on map composer everything works fine. I export the map to pdf file and also goes fine. But when I save and close it and then close the main project and then open it again and then open the map composer that I saved, that map does not show anymore. However, I can still export the map but when it comes to editing I can't because everything is white. The commamd history appears empty. When opened on another computer (PC version) with a different version of QGis works fine.
Here is the printscreen of my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have rendering set to **Rectangle**. It can be changed in map properties. Select your map item and in right panel go to **Item properties --> Main properties** there choose **Render** and hit **Update preview**.

Comment: I am sorry but I have my qgis in portuguese. Can you please printscreen? Sorry and thanks.

Comment: see screenshot here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kq6zomupxh0oo9p/map.jpg?dl=0). Also you can change language localisation in main QGIS configuration. If you change it to english it will help you for works with forums, tutorials etc

Comment: yeah it was helpful thank you. i didn't know i could mark it. that's my first time using this forum 
edit: accepted